# exec doesn't execute command if path contains whitespaces

Tags: php

When I do something like

```
exec("c:\\Program Files (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe --footer-center as  http://bbc.co.uk c:\\test2.pdf",$output);
```

nothing happens. File exists and the the following line returns 1.

```
echo file_exists("c:\\Program Files (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe");
```

If I change it

```
 exec("d:\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe --footer-center as  http://bbc.co.uk c:\\test2.pdf",$output);
```

works fine. Can that be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote your executable's path or escape the white space. Either:

```
exec("c:\\Program^ Files^ (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe --footer-center as  http://bbc.co.uk c:\\test2.pdf",$output);
```

or

```
exec("\"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\" --footer-center as  http://bbc.co.uk c:\\test2.pdf",$output);
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember properly you can use **double quotes** when you have whitespaces in a path name or a file name.

For example:

```
exec('"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --footer-center as  http://bbc.co.uk c:\\test2.pdf',$output);
```

Comment: Yes and also you do not even need to double backslash directories.  exec('"c:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf... works perfectly fine.